# Windows 8 styled popup window using Prism c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, prism, prism-4

I'm trying to create a modal popup window using the windows 8 style popup.

[image: windows 8 styled popup]

If I use the standard prism popup methods as described here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921081%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

I only end up getting new windows. What I want is to have a popup that stays in the context of my window. I just can't find anyway of accomplishing this with a modal popup. Has anyone attempted this or knows of a way this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Although nice, you won't be able to use the PopupWindowAction since inherently it uses a new window. You can, however,  manually add an event handler to the event in your ViewModel from the code behind and do your interactivity there.